# LoopbackJs hooks into relationship urls

Tags: loopbackjs

If I have a url that's generated from a relationship `/threads/{id}/messages` how could I write a `afterRemote` hook that will execute after this query is finished?

Comment: For CRUD operations you should use operation hooks instead of remote hooks. Can you please be more specific what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per stated [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/737) by one of the maintainers of Loopback, you can use the followings to write remote hooks.

- for `POST` **/threads/{id}/messages**

`thread.beforeRemote('*.__create__messages__', function(ctx, inst, next) { ... });`

- for `GET` **threads/{id}/messages**

`thread.beforeRemote('*.__get__messages__', function(ctx, inst, next) { ... });`

- for `DELETE` **threads/{id}/messages**

`thread.beforeRemote('*.__delete__messages__', function(ctx, inst, next) { ... });`